# Expo error - Your project is in SDK version >= 33.0.0, but the expo package version seems to be older

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

Whenever I start my expo managed react native project by `expo start` command
I get this warning -

`Your project is in SDK version >= 33.0.0, but the expo package version seems to be older.`

However my expo project runs successfully. I have also tried changing my  node-modules/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js to this -

```
    var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

But it doesn't works

My `package.json` file -

```
    {
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "^0.5.4",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.2.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.8.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "ultimate-quiz",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Check the version of expo in `app.json` and `package.json`

Comment: @HichamELBSI It is showing ~41.0.1 in package.json and 1.0.0 in app.json, What should I do to update it, will it solve problem

Comment: 1.0.0  ? I was talking about the expo sdk version

Comment: @HichamELBSI It is not mentioned there

Comment: Alright, can you share the package.json file please

Comment: @HichamELBSI I can't share it here, may I edit my question ?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. It was fixed by updating the `expo-cli` to the latest version (4.4.6), as well as updating NodeJS from 10.xx to the latest revision (14.17.0).